# Trouble with reading I2OF5 barcode

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner, motorola, motorola-emdk

I have two barcode scaners - MC9090 and MC9190. Initially under the MC9090 has been written application that reads barcodes and work with SQL databases.On the MC9090 everything works fine on the MS9190 -  problem - not read the barcode type I2OF5 (length = min - 6, max - 8 respectively). Modify the default values (14 and 10 respectively) with the help of a piece of code (on MC9090):

```
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MinimumLength = 6;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength = 8;
```

With MC9190 I can read  I2OF5 barcodes with default parameters(14 and 10 respectively), but I cant read I2OF5 barcodes with lenght min = 6, max = 8.

Tried to send the complete list of parameters like this (already on MC9190):

```
    myReader.Parameters.CodeIdType = CodeIdTypes.None;
    myReader.Parameters.ScanType = ScanTypes.Foreground;
    myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MinimumLength = 6;
    myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength = 8;
    myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.Redundancy = true;
    myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.CheckDigitScheme = I2OF5.CheckDigitSchemes.None;
    myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.ConvertToEAN13 = false;
    myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.ReportCheckDigit = false;
    myReader.Actions.SetParameters();
```

With these parameters, barcodes are read in the demo applications Motorola's great, but not in mine app.

I do check like this:

```
if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.Enabled == true)
    {
        if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.MinimumLength == 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("6");
        }

        if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength == 8)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("8");
        }

        if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.Redundancy == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Redundancy");
        }

        if (_scnAPI.Reader.Parameters.CodeIdType == Symbol.Barcode.CodeIdTypes.None)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CodeType");
        }

        if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.CheckDigitScheme == Symbol.Barcode.I2OF5.CheckDigitSchemes.None)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CheckDigit");
        }
        if (_scnAPI.Reader.Parameters.ScanType == Symbol.Barcode.ScanTypes.Foreground)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("foreground");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App Exit!");
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

All checks are passed, but it is not clear why there is no reading I2OF5 barcodes with the right length to me? Please help me figure out what the problem is.

P.S. 
I use the library Symbol.Barcode, Motorola EMDK 2.4 for .NET. I looked specification of EMDK 2.4 version  is compatible with the 9100- series.

https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/ReleaseNotes/Release%20Notes%20-%20EMDK-M-020403TnV1.htm

Comment: Your code looks ok. Have you checked that the barcode is valid and readable? You can check this online.

Comment: Yes, if i use Motorola DataWedge with length 6,8 I2OF5 barcode reads great.  I cant unrestand what the problem is. It seems that after the launch of the application the length of the barcode again changed to default.

Comment: Yesterday, I modified the sampe application CS_BarcodeSample_1  to read barcodes I2OF5 with length 6,8 parameters and barcode reads great. I use same API class to initiate reader in both app.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question. Please tell us what was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: As I expected, after the launch of the application, and install the barcode parameters, the values are reset to the default values.

Answer (score 1):

My experience: Code128 barcode settings blocked the I2OF5 reading.

```
public FormMain()
        {
            bcl.OnScan +=new Barcode2.OnScanHandler(bcl_OnScan);
            bcl.Config.Decoders.I2OF5.Enabled = true;
            bcl.Config.Decoders.CODE128.Enabled = false;
            bcl.Config.Decoders.I2OF5.MinLength = 6;
            bcl.Config.Decoders.I2OF5.MaxLength = 8;
            bcl.Scan();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Disable the CODE128, enable the I2OF5, and set the parameters of I2OF5. It workes for me!

Comment: Thanks for answering! To improve your answer Please add a bit more detail about what part of the posted code actually resolves the question and how.